# Program with class that uses operator<< and prints a wrong value c++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-keyword

I made a matrix class. This is some part of it.

```
Math::Matrix::Matrix(int row, int col, double * mat)
{
    this->mat = new double[(this->row = row) * (this->col = col)];
    for (int i = 0; i < row * col; i++)
    {
        this->mat[i] = mat[i];
    }
}


Math::Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    if (this->mat != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] this->mat;
    }
}

const Math::Matrix Math::Matrix::multiply(Matrix & A) const
{
    if (!this->is_multipliable(A))
    {
        throw new std::exception("Math::Matrix::multiply : cannot multiply!");
    }
    Matrix B = Matrix(this->row, A.col);
    for (int k = 0; k < this->col; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.col; j++)
            {
                B.mat[i * A.col + j] = this->mat[i * this->col + k] * A.mat[k * A.col + j];
            }
        }
    }
    return B;
}

std::ostream & Math::operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Matrix & m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.col; j++)
        {
            os << m.mat[i*m.col + j] << ' ';
        }
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

This is a part of the matrix class that I wrote, and when I try

```
int main()
{
    A = Math::Matrix(2, 3, new double[6]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
    B = Math::Matrix(3, 4, new double[12]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2 });
    std::cout << A << std::endl;
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
    std::cout << A.multiply(B) << std::endl;
}
```

in main, the program will output some silly numbers such as

```
-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144

-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144


-1.45682e+144 1.07458e-255 3.02386e-294 1.41763e-311

2.122e-314 -7.84591e+298 -1.45684e+144 1.87482e-310

2.9803e-294 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144


-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144

-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144
```

(not debugging)

or

```
1 2 3

4 5 6


-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144

-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144

3.67842e-293 8.81477e-310 3.6647e-293 -1.45682e+144


-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144

-1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144 -1.45682e+144
```

(debugging)

and then throws an exception.

In debug mode, it says that "wntdll.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module ntdll.dll".

I am using visual studio 2017.

What seems to be the problem of this code?

Comment: Your `Matrix` constructor expects a pointer to `double`, but you pass a pointer to array of doubles (which gets deconstructed to `**double`).

Comment: You have memory leak right there, do not use raw pointers when you do not understand how it works

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor and copy assignment operator?

Comment: ```this->mat``` has a type double*. Is that still a problem? @Yksisarvinen

Comment: @user5876164 yes it is, it should be `std::vector<double>`

Comment: May I ask where the code has a memory leak? @Slava

Comment: @user5876164 `main()` function body line 1 and 2. And most probably more problems as I am pretty sure you violate rule of 3/5/0

Comment: @Slava leak in main is unrelated to implementstion of matrix

Comment: @Swift I never said it is and that's why it is in the comment, not answer

Comment: @Swift - it is very related - that is why there is garbage printed - more precisely - the double delete problem is here

Comment: So as usual to properly identify the issue [mcve] is required. Pretty obvious that rule of 3 is violated but we do not have enough information to say for sure.

Comment: General rule of thumb: With C++98, if you're using `new` outside a constructor or `delete` outside a destructor, chances are you're doing it wrong. Since C++11, if you're using `new` outside the construction of a smart pointer, you *are* doing it wrong. (Until you reach the point where you actually *do* know what you're doing, and know when to break rules-of-thumb.)

Comment: BTW, you only need to use `this->` when the function parameter has the same name as the member.  You don't need to use it for member functions, access them directly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that is a matter of personal preference, some fine it better to always use `this` explicitly

Comment: Actually, that's almost all of the code with ```bool is_multipliable(Matrix &A) const;``` . How can I change the code to work properly, or should I really use vectors?

Comment: @user5876164 then you violated rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: @user5876164 `Matrix B = Matrix(this->row, A.col);` -- As others stated, your code violates the rule of 3, and the line I posted in this comment points right at where everything falls apart.  You're making a copy of `Matrix`, and your original `Matrix` class using pointers is not safely-copyable.  No need to look any further -- use `std::vector` and this issue goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use raw pointers you need to understand how it works pretty well. One of the most important rule to follow - [rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), your class definitely violates that. So these lines of code have issue:

```
A = Math::Matrix(2, 3, new double[6]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
B = Math::Matrix(3, 4, new double[12]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2 });
Matrix B = Matrix(this->row, A.col);
```

your objects hold dangling pointers to deleted memory afrter temporaries destroyed. You also have issue with memory leak as you pass pointer to dynamically allocated memory  and then discard it. You better use `std::vector<double>` inside your class which will do all allocations for you and already provides proper copy/move constructros and assignment operators as well as destructor for you. You would not even need to implement destructor at all and use default one.

Comment: yeah, prudent for small matrices. sadly it would not provide move semantics before c++17  (simply those classes didn't had it). would be good to use` reserve` if matrix size never changes

Answer (score 3):

Let's make a guess at how you've defined `Matrix`, then re-write it to be *correct by default*.

```
namespace Math {

class Matrix {
    double * mat; // Bad. Owning raw pointer
    int col, row; // Questionable. std::size_t is the normal type for an index
public:
    Matrix(int row, int col, double * mat); // Bad. Owning raw pointer
    ~Matrix(); // Will be un-necessary under the rule of 0
    const Matrix multiply(Matrix & A) const; // this is usually named "operator *"
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Matrix & m); // Good
};
}
```

And here is how we tidy it up

```
namespace Math {

class Matrix {
    std::vector<double> mat; 
    std::size_t col, row; 

public:
    Matrix(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) 
     : row(row), col(col), mat(row * col, 0) 
    {}

    template <typename InputIterator>
    Matrix(std::size_t row, std::size_t col, InputIterator it) // copy from any sequence of doubles
     : Matrix(row, col) // delegate to 2-arg constructor to initialises fields
    {
        std::copy_n(it, row * col, mat.begin());
    }

    double & data(std::size_t c, std::size_t r) // Convinience
    { return mat[(r * col) + c]; }

    double data(std::size_t c, std::size_t r) const // Overload for const
    { return mat[(r * col) + c]; }

    friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix & lhs, const Matrix & rhs)
    {
        if (!lhs.is_multipliable(rhs))
        {
            // MSVC includes this as a non-standard extension
            // std::runtime_error is a portable replacement
            throw new std::exception("Math::Matrix::multiply : cannot multiply!");
        }
        Matrix result = Matrix(lhs.row, rhs.col);
        for (int k = 0; k < lhs.col; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lhs.row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < rhs.col; j++)
                {
                    result.data(i, j) += lhs.data(i, k) * rhs.data(k, j);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Matrix & m);    
    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is,       Matrix & m);    
};
}
```

Note that `std::exception` isn't defined to have a [`const char *` accepting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/standard-library/exception-class) [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception)

Comment: I would return `double` by value from const version of `data()` and that loops do not look right - you assign to `result.data(i, j)` in loop discarding previous values. This is coming from OP's code, but your improvement made it obvious.

Comment: @Slava I think I was mentally translating `T` -> `double` from a `Matrix<T>`, good point

Comment: I think it should be `result.data(i, j) += ...` so +1 for well written code that made it obvious.

Comment: @Slava lets better define operator[]? I have working example, though written for embedded platform, no smart pointer. I would use smart pointer instead of vector before c++17

Comment: @Swift `operator[]` cannot have 2 parameters and I do not quite understand what's wrong with  `std::vector` before c++17

Comment: @Swift the convention used by Eigen and others is `operator()`. It would  be nice to be able to `lhs[pair_like]` for anything that you could `auto [r, c] = pair_like`, and it would also be nice to `lhs[{r, c}]`, but those are mutually incompatible afaik

Comment: @Slava can do. operator[] would return nested class MatrixRow that doesn't require to own data, it got own operator[]. before c++17 - problems with copy elision and library vector didn't had move. And I also used Eigen's operator(). operator[]  allowed to work with matrix row by row - quite often required operation in some areas

Comment: @Swift I do not think creating `MatrixRow` and possible implications on performance worse the effort just for ability to write `matrix[i][j]` instead of `matrix.data( i, j )`. And why do you think `std::vector` does not support move semantics since c++11? It certainly does

Comment: @Slava not by documentation, certainly not supported on our platform as well. cost of that was checked. if Row wasn't owning resource, it just had to refer to Matrix created it, inlining optimization ate all  but creation of integer field expenses. also can write someting like `matrix[i] = Vector(.....)`. matrix.data() is mouthful, matrix(i,j)  is better and matches most of libraries that exist.

Comment: @Swift by documentation `std::vector` support move semantics since C++11 - prooflink http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector Your platform may have that issue but it is unlikely OP would have it as this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This line is a bad idea

```
A = Math::Matrix(2, 3, new double[6]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
```

You allocate memory for initialized array, but you are unable to free that memory, because pointer to array was not saved.

You don't have copy constructor and assignment, so after your temporal matrix is destroyed, A would retain pointer with invalid value because its fields were shallow-copied.

Define at least copy constructor and assignment operator, recommended to add move constructor and moving assignment and default constructor. Constructor that uses array may be created using `std::initializer_list`

Comment: @YSC: the constructor uses the pointer and discards it, so it is never deleted in OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is probably the copy/move operators that you did not show.

As soon as you have a raw pointer holding dynamic memory, thou shallst implement copy and move constructors and copy and move assignement operators or explicitely delete them, because their implicitely defined version cannot correctly handle that.

So this could be acceptable (I say acceptable, not good, because unless you are implementing a generic container, you should avoid raw dynamic memory allocation and only rely on standard containers):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Math {

    class Matrix {
    public:
        int row;
        int col;
        double *mat;              // beware rule of 3/5

        Matrix(int row, int col, double *mat);
        ~Matrix();
        Matrix(const Matrix&) = delete;    // explicitely delete what we don't define
        Matrix(Matrix&&) = delete;
        Matrix operator = (const Matrix&) = delete;
        Matrix operator = (Matrix&&) = delete;
    };
}
Math::Matrix::Matrix(int row, int col, double * mat)
{
    this->mat = new double[(this->row = row) * (this->col = col)];
    for (int i = 0; i < row * col; i++) {
        this->mat[i] = mat[i];
    }
}


Math::Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    if (this->mat != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] this->mat;
    }
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Math::Matrix & m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.col; j++)
        {
            os << m.mat[i*m.col + j] << ' ';
        }
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
int main(){

    double *m = new double[6]{1,2,3,4,5,6};  // store the automatic memory pointer ...
    Math::Matrix mat(2, 3, m); // only uses the direct ctor
    delete[] m;                              // to be able to delete it!
    std::cout << mat;

    return 0;
}
```

But when you write:

```
A = Math::Matrix(2, 3, new double[6]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
```

- you first allocate memory for an array of 6 doubles that will never be deallocated since you do not strore the pointer -> memory leak assured
- then you almost correctly construct a temporary matrix
- that you **assign** to an already existing object...

The default move operator will *copy* the `mat` member from the temporary matrix to A, and then the temporary matrix will be destroyed freeing the memory pointer to by the `mat` member -> dangling pointer assured

That dangling pointer is the cause for Undefined Behaviour and weird outputs.

BTW my version with deleted assignment operators will raise a compilation error on that line, which is the red light warning: beware something will soon break near that point...

TL/DR: if you can, avoid direct management of allocated memory, and if you cannot avoid that, then do implement copy/move constructors and assignment operators or explicitely delete those that you do not define.

Comment: essentislly , tl/dr is: if you can't follow rule of nothing,  do rule of five :P